# Como eu posso pegar o resultado do imc para e colocar em outra TextView??? Eu tentei dessa maneira

Tags: java, android, app

```
 public void btCalcularIMC(View v){
        float altura, peso, imc;
        altura = Float.parseFloat(edAltura.getText().toString());
        peso = Float.parseFloat(edPeso.getText().toString());

        imc = peso / (altura*2);

        tvResultado.setText(String.format("%.2f", imc));

        try {
            int classific = Integer.parseInt(tvResultado.getText().toString());
            if (0 > 18.5) {
                tvResultado.setText("Você está abaixo de peso + imc +");
            } else if (18.6 >= 24.9) {
                tvResultado.setText("Você está no peso ideal (PARABÉNS) + imc +  ");
            } else if (25 >= 29.9) {
                tvResultado.setText("Levemente acima do peso + imc +  ");
            } else if (30.0 >= 34.9) {
                tvResultado.setText("Obseidade grau 1 + imc + ");
            } else if (35.0 >= 39.9) {
                tvResultado.setText("Obesidade grau 2 (Severa) + imc + ");
            } else {`insira o código aqui`
                tvResultado.setText("Obesidade grau 3 (Mórbido) + imc +");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu if else sempre está sendo true, você precisa inserir a variavel imc para fazer as comparações, o correto seria:

```
public void btCalcularIMC(View v) {
    float altura, peso, imc;
    altura = Float.parseFloat(edAltura.getText().toString());
    peso = Float.parseFloat(edPeso.getText().toString());

    imc = peso / (altura * 2);
    try {
        if (imc > 0 && imc <= 18.5) {
            tvResultado.setText("Você está abaixo de peso" + imc);
        } else if (imc >= 18.6 && imc <= 24.9) {
            tvResultado.setText("Você está no peso ideal (PARABÉNS)" + imc);
        } else if (imc >= 25 && imc <= 29.9) {
            tvResultado.setText("Levemente acima do peso" + imc);
        } else if (imc >= 30.0 && imc <= 34.9) {
            tvResultado.setText("Obseidade grau 1 " + imc);
        } else if (imc >= 35.0 && imc <= 39.9) {
            tvResultado.setText("Obesidade grau 2 (Severa)" + imc);
        } else {
            tvResultado.setText("Obesidade grau 3 (Mórbido)" + imc);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado , me ajudou muito